# MYSQL - Find the ID of the record just added

Tags: php, mysql

OK, so here is my scenario - you may disagree with what I'm attempting to do but I have my reasons.
The user is able to upload various information to the database, I also want them to be able to upload a picture at the same time. Now for various reasons I want to store the image with the file name the ID number of the record I'm adding (I have an ID column as the primary which auto-increments). Obviously I would have to store the file extension in the database too.
Now is there a way I can add the record and then know what ID was set so that I can save the image? I don't want to query and select the highest ID as that could go wrong if two people were to submit the form at the same time.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running an insert in PHP, you can get the `AUTO_INCREMENT` ID from `$mysqli->insert_id` (where $mysqli is a `MySQLi` connection object), `$pdo->lastInsertId` (where $pdo is a `PDO` connection object), or `mysql_insert_id()` (if you're still using `MySQL`, which you shouldn't be) without having to run another query.

Comment: could you elaborate? I'm unfamiliar with pdo.

Comment: @cainy393 what are you using in PHP to run the query?

Comment: erm... nothing really mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (Some, Stuff) VALUES (Some, Values);")

Comment: @cainy393 `mysql_insert_id()` will return the last insert ID if you run the query with `mysql_query()`.

Answer (score 3):

[`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) will give you the `ID` that was auto-generated:

> ... returns a `BIGINT` (64-bit) value representing the first
>   automatically generated value that was set for an `AUTO_INCREMENT`
>   column by the most recently executed `INSERT` statement to affect such
>   a column. For example, after inserting a row that generates an
>   `AUTO_INCREMENT` value, you can get the value like this:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
>         -> 195
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems like it will work. Although is there the possibility that if several people submit the form at the same time it could select the wrong one?

Comment: @user1821586 a little search would tell you. Please always do some research before posting question. Try to find solution and when you are stuck than post it here!

Comment: @user1821586 It will work if several people submit the form at the same time, because it will give you the last auto-generated value for the *current connection*.  Since each form submission will use a different connection, they will not interfere.

Comment: I see, thanks. I have researched this although I thought there would be problems with multiple submissions at the same time. But thank you for clearing that up, problem solved! :)

Comment: Ok so when I did this and then tried to name the file whatever the query returned it name it "Resource id #11". Why is this?

Comment: @cainy393 you need to get the data from the mysql result with one of the `mysql_fetch_` methods.